# Как VS code найти и заменить текст?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как найти и заменить текст в VS code.
Я знаю где находится поиск и нахожу то, что хочу заменить, но замена происходит во всех файлах.
А мне нужно.

1. Заменить только в одном файле.
2. Заменить в какой то конкретной папке.
3. Если возможно заменить выделенном фрагменте.
4. Если возможно конкретных файлах.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Заменить только в одном файле**, в открытом файле <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, пример в ответе от @Genesis
2. **Заменить в какой то конкретной папке.**

   - Правый клик по папке
   - Выбрать `Find in folder...`
   - Откроется поиск с уже установленными настройками для поиска и замены в одной конкретной папке, пример
     [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. **Заменить в выделенном фрагменте.**

   - выделите текст, нужный блок
   - нажмите <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
   - выберите `Find in Selection`
     [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   - результат, обратите внимание, что найдено только 2 значения, хотя их больше.
     [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. **Поиск и замена в конкретных файлах.**

   - перейдите в поиск и нажмите на три точки под строкой `Toggle Search Details`
     [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   - в строке `files to include` укажите файл или файлы, с которыми вам надо поработать
   - результат
     [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

можно вбить сначало в глобальном поиске а потом в файле ctr+r и менять то что нужно  если вы об этом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]